# Choose the duplicates and pick based on non duplicate column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I need to write a query on below table to fetch the records only when the same email and name is shared by more than 1 member. In below example, I need resultset as

```
100          a@a.com       nameA  
300           a@a.com      nameA
```

Table

```
Member  email               name  
100           a@a.com       nameA  
100           a@a.com       nameA  
300           a@a.com       nameA  
200           b@b.com       nameB
```

Comment: Your question is still not clear.

Comment: According to your description, why do you expect member  200? do you need member 100 instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you have typo and you mean `100` instead of `200` in your expected result. If so, then there is one way:

```
with your_table(Member, email , name ) as (
    select 100,'a@a.com','nameA' union all
    select 100,'a@a.com','nameA' union all
    select 300,'a@a.com','nameA' union all
    select 200,'b@b.com','nameB'  
)

-- below is actual query:

select distinct your_table.* 
from your_table
inner join (
    select  email , name from your_table
    group by email ,  name
    having count(distinct Member) > 1
) t
on your_table.email = t.email and your_table.name = t.name
```

Comment: Apologize fahad and oto, I corrected my resultset. It should be 100 as you both assumed